# Selenium login Instragram why it has to login again when open new url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I login Instragram and open some instragram page like this code.

```
url=['https://www.instagram.com']
user_names = []
user_comments = []
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
driver.get(url[0])
time.sleep(3)
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))

username.clear()
username.send_keys('myusername')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('mypassword')
Login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/Co_3ALaDC3i/')
```

when driver.get() new url it show login button again. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need a brief pause between logging in and navigating to the new page. The code is running so fast, it's logging in but before the page can redirect and log you in, the script is telling the browser to navigate to a new page resulting in the log in button again.

Try the code below. I've added a wait after the login button is clicked that should wait until the page transitions before trying to change the URL.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url=['https://www.instagram.com']
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url[0])

user_names = []
user_comments = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys('myusername')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys('mypassword')

log_in = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")))
log_in.click()
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(log_in))
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/Co_3ALaDC3i/')

driver.quit()
```